# I can't add new option from select section in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

In my Laravel 8 project, there is a page called **Tag List**. I want to add two new tags to **Create Tag** and **Edit** pages in this **Tag List** page. As an example, I leave the `edit.blade.php` below. Lastly, I added the **Collection Tag** and **Brand Tag** in the `edit.blade.php` file. I added these tags here and uploaded them to the page, but when I select one of these new tags from the page and update it, it is not considered valid and still appears in the old tag. I don't know if I need to do something from the **controller** part for these tags to be valid or if I need to do something else from somewhere else.

**edit.blade.php**

```
@extends('admin.layouts.app')

@section('head_scripts')
    <script src="{{ asset('js/jscolor/jscolor.min.js') }}"></script>
@endsection

@section('content')
    <div class="p-5">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'tags/'.$tag->id,'method' => 'PUT','files' => true)) }}
                {{ Form::token() }}
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header row mx-0">
                        <div class="mr-auto">
                            Tag
                        </div>
                        <div class="ml-auto">
                            {{ Form::submit('Update',['class' => 'btn btn-success btn-sm py-2 px-4 rounded']) }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                                        {{ Form::label('name','Tag Name')  }}
                                        {{ Form::text('tags[name]',$tag->name,['required',"class"=>"form-control form-control-sm","placeholder"=>"Name"]) }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-1">
                                        {{ Form::label('order','Tag Order')  }}
                                        {{ Form::text('tags[order]',$tag->order,['required',"class"=>"form-control form-control-sm","placeholder"=>"Name"]) }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                                        {{ Form::label('isMainTag','Is Main Tag', 'Collection Tag', 'Brand Tag')  }} 
                                        <select name="tags[isMainPage]" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                                            <option @if($tag->isMainPage==0) selected @endif value="0">Normal Tag</option>
                                            <option @if($tag->isMainPage==1) selected @endif value="1">Main Feed Tag</option>
                                            <option @if($tag->isMainPage==2) selected @endif value="2">Collection Tag</option>
                                            <option @if($tag->isMainPage==3) selected @endif value="3">Brand Tag</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-2">

                                        {{ Form::label('color','Course Background Color')  }}
                                        <input  type="text" data-jscolor="{}" value="{{ $tag->color  }}" class="color-picker  form-control form-control-sm {{$errors->has('color') ? ' border-danger' : ''}}" id="color" name="tags[color]" value="{{old('color')}}">
                                        <small class="form-text text-danger">{!! $errors->first('color') !!}</small>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-1">
                                            @if($tag->color!=null)
                                                <div class="border" style='background:{{$tag->color}};width: 100px;height: 100px' >     </div>
                                            @endif
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-5">
                                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                                            {{ Form::label('categories','Categories')  }}
                                            {{ Form::select('categories[]',$categories->pluck('name','id') ,$tag->categories->pluck('id') , ['id'=>'tags','style'=>'width:100%','class'=>'form-control form-control-sm searchable_dropdown_multiple','multiple' => 'multiple']) }}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-12 my-5">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                                        {{ Form::label('type','Tag Type')  }}
                                        {{ Form::select('fields[type]',['Collection' => 'Collection Tag','Normal' => 'Normal Tag','NonPayout' => 'Non-Payout Tag'],$tag->getField('type') ?? 'Normal',["class"=>"form-control form-control-sm"]) }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                                        {{ Form::label('name','Brand Name')  }}
                                        {{ Form::text('fields[brand_name]',$tag->getField('brand_name'),["class"=>"form-control form-control-sm","placeholder"=>"Brand Name"]) }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                                        {{ Form::label('description','Brand Description')  }}
                                        {{ Form::text('fields[brand_description]',$tag->getField('brand_description'),["class"=>"form-control form-control-sm","placeholder"=>"Brand Description"]) }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                                        {{ Form::label('logo','Brand Logo')  }}
                                        {{ Form::file('file_fields[brand_logo]',["class"=>"form-control form-control-sm",'accept'=>'.png,.jpg,.jpeg']) }}
                                        @if($tag->getField('brand_logo')!=null)
                                            <div class="mt-2 text-center">
                                                <p>Current Logo</p>
                                                <img src="{{ $tag->getField('brand_logo')}}" height="100" width="100">
                                            </div>
                                        @endif
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

                {{ Form::close() }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection


@section('scripts')
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('body').on('click','.delete-lecture-btn',function () {
                var result = confirm('Are You Sure Delete Lecture?');
                if(result){
                    $(this).parents('.lecture_card').remove();
                }

            })
            $('.add_lecture').click(function () {
                var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
                console.log(timestamp);
                html = '';
                html += '<div class="row my-2 border p-3 lecture_card">';
                html += '<div class="col-lg-12 row mx-0">';
                html += '<div class="mr-auto">';
                html += '<div class="badge badge-info text-white">New</div>';
                html += '</div>';
                html += '<div class="ml-auto">';
                html += '<button class="delete-lecture-btn btn btn-danger btn-sm">x</button>';
                html += '</div>';
                html += '</div>';
                html += '<div class="col-lg-3">';
                html += '<div class="row">';
                html += '<div class="col-lg-12">';
                html += '<small>Title</small>';
                html += '<input type="text" name="lectures_new['+timestamp+'][title]" value="" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Title" required>';
                html += '</div>';
                html += '<div class="col-lg-6">';
                html += '<small>Order</small>';
                html += '<input type="text" name="lectures_new['+timestamp+'][order]" value="" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Order" required>';
                html += '</div>';
                html += '<div class="col-lg-6">';
                html += '<small>Length (Second)</small>';
                html += '<input type="text" name="lectures_new['+timestamp+'][length]" readonly value="" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Length" required>';
                html += '</div>';
                html += '</div>';
                html += '</div>';
                html += '<div class="col-lg-3">';
                html += '<small>Description</small>';
                html += '<textarea type="text" name="lectures_new['+timestamp+'][description]"  rows="8" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Description" required></textarea>';
                html += '</div>';
                html += '<div class="col-lg-6">';
                html += '<div class="row">';
                html += '<div class="col-lg-12">';
                html += '<small>New Audio</small><br>';
                html += '<input type="file" name="lectures_new['+timestamp+'][new_audio_file]" accept=".mp3,audio/*" class="form-control form-control-sm">';
                html += '</div>';
                html += '</div>';
                html += '</div>';
                html += '</div>';
                $('.lectures_place').append(html);

            });
        });
    </script>


@endsection
```

**TagController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Course;
use App\CourseCategory;
use App\Tag;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Yajra\DataTables\DataTables;

class TagController extends Controller
{

    public function index(){
        //$courses = Course::all();
        return view('admin.tags.index');
    }

    public function show($tag_id){
        $tag = Tag::findOrFail($tag_id);
        return view('admin.tags.show',['tag' => $tag]); 
    }

    public function create(){
        $categories = CourseCategory::all();

        return view('admin.tags.create',['categories' => $categories]);
    }

    public function store(Request $request){
        $tag = Tag::create($request->tags);
        $this->setTagCategories($request->categories,$tag->id);
        return redirect('/tags');
    }
    public function update(Request $request,$tag_id){
        $tag = Tag::findOrFail($tag_id);
        $tag->update($request->tags);
        $this->setTagCategories($request->categories,$tag_id);

        if(isset($request->fields)){
            foreach ($request->fields as $key => $value){
                $tag->setField($key,$value);
            }
        }

        if(isset($request->file_fields)){
            foreach ($request->file_fields as $key => $value){
                $tag->setFileField($key,$value);
            }
        }

        return redirect('/tags');
    }
    public function edit($tag_id){
        $tag = Tag::findOrFail($tag_id);
        $categories = CourseCategory::all();

        return view('admin.tags.edit',['tag' => $tag,'categories' => $categories]);
    }


    private function setTagCategories($categories,$tag_id){
        $db_data = [];
        if($categories!=null)
            foreach ($categories as $key => $category){
                if($category!=null && $category!='')
                    $db_data[] = [
                        'tag_id'=> $tag_id,
                        'category_id'=> $category,
                    ];
            }
        if(!empty($db_data)){
            DB::table('category_tag_pivots')->where('tag_id','=',$tag_id)->delete();
            DB::table('category_tag_pivots')->insert($db_data);
        }
    }


    public function destroy($category_id){
        DB::table('course_category_pivots')->where('category_id','=',$category_id)->delete();
        DB::table('course_categories')->where('id','=',$category_id)->delete();
    }



    public function getDataTable()
    {
        return DataTables::of(Tag::select(['id','name','color','order','isMainPage']))
            ->addColumn('course_number', function (Tag $tag) {
                return count($tag->courses);
            })->addColumn('categories', function (Tag $tag) {
                return $tag->categories->implode('name',',');
            })
            ->addColumn('action', function($row){
                $btn = '<a href="/tags/'.$row['id'].'" class="edit btn btn-info btn-sm">View</a>';

                $btn = $btn.'<a href="/tags/'.$row['id'].'/edit" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit</a>';

                $btn = $btn.'<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-remote="/tags/'.$row['id'].'" class="edit btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-delete">Del</a>';

                return $btn;

            })->make(true);
    }
}
```

**category_tag_pivots_table.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateCategoryTagPivotsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('category_tag_pivots', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('tag_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
            $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('tags')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('course_categories')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');

        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('category_tag_pivots');
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "it is not considered valid and still appears in the old tag" ?

Comment: @JunPan In other words, I enter the Tag List page from the admin panel and enter the edit section from there, select the Collection Tag from the options I added and update it, but when I return to the Tag List page, the old tag still appears. When I enter the edit section again, the Collection Tag that I marked there appears to be selected.